# IAsyncResult completing synchronously

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I would like to ask a question regarding IAsyncResult's isCompleted property.

i have a

```
IAsyncResult worker;
```

and a class that does

```
worker = slave.BeginWork();
```

on my main thread, and then it checks in it's update loop if the worker has finished by doing:

```
if(worker.IsCompleted)
{
    int result = slave.EndWork(worker);
}
```

would this cause any issue?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using this in 2018?

Comment: Game's main-thread being over sensitive... Not much of a reason though

Comment: [TAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/implementing-the-task-based-asynchronous-pattern) Should not have much of a performance impact. IAsyncResult is a bit out dated.

Comment: @FilipCordas Awesome :) I guess i am just an old fart still using the telegraph hehe

Answer (score 0):

> TAP Should not have much of a performance impact. IAsyncResult is a bit out dated. – Filip Cordas